# How to paginate external API in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning to use Django Rest Framework, so as exercise I want to consume [Github User REST API](https://api.github.com/users) listing the users and save on a local database a specific user info, also I want that listing to be paginated. I have the following viewsets file:

```
import requests
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet

from users.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer


class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def github(self, request):
        data = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users')
        return Response(data=data.json())
```

I'm able to list my users, and I know how to paginate the queryset but how do I paginate the github response ?

another question, in this snippet my routes stay like:

api/user

api/user/github

​

Is there a way to create a separate view just for the github so I can something like:

api/user

api/github/user

api/github/repository

​

and then be able to use filter field on api/user and api/github/user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use custom pagination :

```
import requests
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
from users.models import User
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from rest_framework import status
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, PageNotAnInteger, EmptyPage


class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    @action(detail=False, methods=['GET'])
    def github(self, request):
        limit = self.request.query_params.get("limit", 10)
        offset = self.request.query_params.get("offset", 1)
        users = requests.get('https://api.github.com/users')
        results = users.json()

        try:
            paginator = Paginator(results, limit)
        except:
            paginator = Paginator(results, limit)

        try:
            results = paginator.page(offset)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            results = paginator.page(offset)
        except EmptyPage:
            results = []

        api_count = paginator.count
        api_next = None if not results.has_next() else results.next_page_number()
        api_previous = None if not results.has_previous() else results.previous_page_number()

        data = {
            'count': api_count,
            'next': api_next,
            'previous': api_previous,
            'results': list(results)
        }

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```